# AWS ECS docker Invalid 'volumesFrom' setting. Unknown container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run service with following definition on AWS ECS cluster. But I am getting an error. Invalid 'volumesFrom' setting. Unknown container: 'docker-data'. I have separately launched docker-data service but my other service is still unable to find my data container. Below are task definitions.

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [{
        "name": "docker-data",
        "image": "jaigouk/data-only-container",
        "memory": 128
    }],
    "family": "docker-data"
}

{
    "containerDefinitions": [{
        "image": "my/work-image",
        "name": "image2",
        "memory": 512,
        "portMappings": [{
            "hostPort": 8040,
            "containerPort": 8040,
            "protocol": "tcp"
        }],
        "volumesFrom": [{
            "sourceContainer": "docker-data"
        }]
    }],
    "family": "console"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're defining 2 containers in two task definitions. In this case, docker-data is not known.

Here is one of my working example

```
{  
"taskDefinitionArn":"arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:xxxx:task-definition/vc-p-tim:15",
"networkMode":"bridge",
"status":"ACTIVE",
"revision":15,
"taskRoleArn":null,
"containerDefinitions":[  
    {  
        "volumesFrom":[  

        ],
        "memory":2048,
        "extraHosts":null,
        "dnsServers":null,
        "disableNetworking":null,
        "dnsSearchDomains":null,
        "hostname":null,
        "essential":true,
        "entryPoint":null,
        "mountPoints":[  
            {  
                "containerPath":"/apps",
                "sourceVolume":"tinymce-data",
                "readOnly":null
            }
        ],
        "name":"tim-srv",
        "ulimits":null,
        "dockerSecurityOptions":null,
        "environment":[  

        ],
        "links":null,
        "workingDirectory":null,
        "readonlyRootFilesystem":null,
        "image":"xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/tinymce-server:latest",
        "command":null,
        "user":null,
        "dockerLabels":null,
        "logConfiguration":null,
        "cpu":0,
        "privileged":null,
        "memoryReservation":null
    },
    {  
        "volumesFrom":[  
            {  
                "readOnly":null,
                "sourceContainer":"tim-srv"
            }
        ],
        "memory":256,
        "extraHosts":null,
        "dnsServers":null,
        "disableNetworking":null,
        "dnsSearchDomains":null,
        "hostname":null,
        "essential":true,
        "entryPoint":null,
        "mountPoints":[  

        ],
        "name":"tim-api",
        "ulimits":null,
        "dockerSecurityOptions":null,
        "links":null,
        "workingDirectory":null,
        "readonlyRootFilesystem":null,
        "image":"xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/tinymce-api:0118171510",
        "command":null,
        "user":null,
        "dockerLabels":null,
        "logConfiguration":null,
        "cpu":0,
        "privileged":null,
        "memoryReservation":null
    }
],
"volumes":[  
    {  
        "host":{  
            "sourcePath":"tinymce-data"
        },
        "name":"tinymce-data"
    }
],
"family":"vc-p-tim"
```

}

Comment: I am defining containers in two separate task definitions. So ecs is unable to find data container. I read complete aws ecs documentation and it seems that doing this is impossible. It only work by combining all task definitions under single family. Your example is correct.